# Javascript alert button OK button

Tags: javascript

I want to ask about javascript alert button.
Is it possible to do anything (e.g: redirect, clear form) after I clicked the OK button on the **alert** button?

Comment: If you’re asking if you can bind a `"click"` callback handler on `alert()` dialogs, no.

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply your function right after the alert:

```
alert('something');//execution is halted until ok button is pressed
foo(); // calls the foo method after ok button is pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `alert` to use a `confirm` window

```
var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to clear the form?');
if (response){
   // clear the form
   console.log('clearing the form approved');
}
```

The `confirm` window is similar to the `alert` except it shows <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons. It returns a `bool` result depending on the user's choice.

Like the `alert` window, it halts program/script execution until the user makes a decision